# Stochastic integral wrt the compensated Poisson random measure

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, levy-processes

I am solving the exercises in a book I have about Lévy processes ("Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus", Applebaum, 2003), and I cannot get my head around an exercise that seems rather simple. I have been trying to use different lemmas to prove the following result, but I'm not convinced by any.

I am trying to prove that the stochastic integral
$$
\int_0^T\int_A H(t,x)\,\tilde{N}(dt,dx) = \int_0^T\int_A H(t,x)\,N(dt,dx) - \int_0^T\int_A H(t,x)\,\nu(dx)dt 
$$
is **finite** (almost surely), where $H$ satisfies the regular square-integrability condition and $\nu$ is the Poisson random measure.

Does somebody know how to prove this result?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that the stochastic integral

$$\int_0^T \int_A H(t,x) \tilde{N}(dt,dx)$$

is almost surely finite if $H$ is square integrable, but this is in general *not* true for the integrals

$$\int_0^T \int_A H(t,x) N(dt,dx) \qquad \text{and} \int_0^T \int_A H(t,x) \, \nu(dx) \, dt.$$

This means that we can in general not write

$$\int_0^T \int_A H(t,x) \tilde{N}(dt,dx) = \int_0^T \int_A H(t,x) N(dt,dx)- \int_0^T \int_A H(t,x) \nu(dx) \, dt.$$

---

Now let $H$ be square-integrable, i.e.

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T \int_A H(t,x)^2 \nu(dx) \, dt \right)<\infty. \tag{1}$$

Then it follows from Itô's isometry that

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \left| \int_0^T \int_A H(t,x) \tilde{N}(dt,dx) \right|^2 \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T \int_A H(t,x)^2 \, \nu(dx) \, dt \right) \stackrel{(1)}{<} \infty.$$

This shows that $\int_0^T \int_A H(t,x) \tilde{N}(dt,dx) \in L^2(\mathbb{P})$; hence, in particular, $$\int_0^T \int_A H(t,x) \tilde{N}(dt,dx)<\infty\quad \text{almost surely.}$$

Comment: mmh if I'm being honest I don't know how the Itô isommetry could help: to apply it I would need to square both sides of the initial equation above described (something I did not want to do since I thought I had to prove that the integral is finite in $L_1(P)$ and not $L_2(P)$) and then take expectations, which I believe would take me to something like $0=0$ since the left hand side is a martingale and the terms in the right-hand side cancel each other out. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Alfie If the left-hand side is in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$, it is automatically in $L^1(\mathbb{P})$, right? And again, in general, we cannot expect that the right-hand side makes sense, i.e. we can in general not split up the integral in this way.

Comment: yes you're right indeed, I mixed up a couple of things. So then to prove this is finite one would only need to write:
$\mathbb E[\int H^2\tilde{N}(dt,dz)] = \mathbb E[\int_0^t H^2 \nu(dz)dt] - \mathbb E[\int_0^t H^2 \nu(dz)dt]$, and then conclude by saying that since the right hand side equals $0$, the integral on the left hand side must be finite?

Comment: @Alfie No, you didn't apply Itô's isometry correctly. Itô's isometry states that $$\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int H \tilde{N} \right)^2 \right] = \mathbb{E} \left( \int \int H^2 \, \nu(dz) \, dt \right).$$

Comment: true sorry I was aware of that but I mistyped it. Unfortunately, I've become increasingly confused about this easy problem. I have that
$$
\mathbb E\int H^2\,\nu(dz)dt = \mathbb E\left(\int H\,N(dt,dz) - \int H\,\nu(dz)dt \right)^2
$$
My problem is the right hand side, I am unsure whether the isometry also applies to the integral against $N(dt,dz)$. Moreover, I still cannot even guess how to conclude the right hand side is finite...

Comment: @Alfie Sorry, but that's still not Itô's isometry. It would be a good start to realize that the equality $$\int H d\tilde{N} = \int H dN - \int H d\nu$$ does in general **not** hold.

Comment: Dear @saz what conditions are sufficient on $H$ so that the equality you wrote in the first part of your answer holds?